# Error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected '{"code":"sting"…' to deeply equal {"code":"string"…'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am trying to do a test but it gives me this error. The test consists of this

```js
   test('Should fire show-message-alert-manager when getVerificationError is called the second time', (done) => {

      const listener = (event) => {
        
        assert.deepEqual(JSON.stringify(event.detail), JSON.stringify(GET_VERIFICATION_ERROR_ALERT_SECOND_TIME));
        el.removeEventListener('show-message-alert-manager', listener);
        done();
      };
      el._getVerificationAttempt = true;
      el.addEventListener('show-message-alert-manager', listener);
      el.getVerificationError();
      
    });
```

but it gives me this error: Error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected '{"code":"get-verification-exit-error"…' to deeply equal '{"code":"get-verification-exit-error"…'

I appreciate all the support I can get for this.

Comment: `deepEqual` would expect a nested object but its getting strings.

Comment: I'm also gonna point out that `JSON.stringify` can stringify objects differently based on when the keys were added/defined. So two objects that are the exact same in structure can be serialized to different strings... Anyways, you should really pay attention to the comment above; don't use JSON.stringify - compare the objects directly.

Comment: when I delete what you tell me this happens to me:   Error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected { …(2) } to deeply equal { …(2) } (node_modules/chai/chai.js:250)
          at BbvaManagerDocumentVerification._fireEvent (src/ManagerDocumentVerificationMixin.js:423:12)
          at ManagerDocumentVerification._showMessageAlert (src/ManagerDocumentVerificationMixin.js:439:12)
          at DocumentVerification.showModalVerificationExitError (src/ManagerDocumentVerification.js:6979:10)